# flutter_downloadloader keeps faling to download a file

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When trying to download a pdf file, it showing download started and then failed in the taskbar.

This is happening on few devices (android 10). There is no issue on other devices

```
  await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: Uri.parse(url).toString(),
        savedDir: _path,
        fileName: _fileName,
        showNotification: true,
        openFileFromNotification: true
      );
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? Can you provide some more information on when/where/how it fails?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**saveInPublicStorage: true** Worked

```
await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
         url: Uri.parse(url).toString(),
         savedDir: _path,
         fileName: _fileName,
         showNotification: true,
         openFileFromNotification: true,
         saveInPublicStorage: true);
```